# jQuery on mouseout do nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some effects in my menu, which works fine, but these effects shouldn't trigger on a menupoint which belongs to class "active". How should I do that? Using eval or similar things?

To sum it up: I want to deny an effect if the trigger has a special class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of your mouse events, use `.hasClass()` in an `if()` statement:

```
$('.selector').mouseout(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        return;
    }

    // The rest of your code.
});
```

Here, the `if()` checks to see whether the element the event was fired on has the class `active`. If it does, the function `return`s, not executing any more code inside it.

You haven't given any code or HTML to work with, so this is a general solution. Please update your question with more detail so I can give you a better answer.

Comment: You shouldn't use "return false;", just to "return;". Returning a value of false has a lot more side-effects that can confuse other things on the site if you don't know to expect them. Read this for more info: [Misusing return false](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false)

Comment: hell yeah, sorry that was definitely one of my dumbest questions ever :)

Comment: @LoganF.Smyth Thanks for the heads up. TIL `return false` is bad. I've edited my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

In the trigger function, just wrap your code with

```
if ($(this).not('.active')) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JamWaffles and Cito's way works and are the most effective but just as an alternative you could also do it like this, first fetch the class value:

```
var className = $('.myclass').attr('class');
```

Then you want to check the value

```
if (className != 'whatever') {

    // animate and stuff etc

}
```

But like I said, the other methods are better so you might as well use the built in features of jQuery such as `hasClass` - just showing theres more than one way to tackle problems :)

Answer (score 1):

bind to `(not) active` like this:
`$('.menuitem:not(.active)').live('mouseout',function(){});`

Comment: This is the best solution if the "active" class does not change in the lifetime of the page.

Comment: Ok, using `live()` it works even if the "active" class changes - but this is now less performant, particularly when using mouseout events. Btw, `live()` has also been deprecated. If the "active" class does not change (which may be the case), your former solution was much better.